# How does one create database tables (MSSQL) to handle notifications to users and system notifications to all users?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, database-normalization

I would like to create a notification system for a web application I'm working on. I'm having trouble designing a database that is laid out in a "correct" format. This is what I would like to accomplish:

- Have different notification types, such as Office, User, Client, Vendors, and System. User, Client, and Vendors are different "classes" of users that can login to different portals on the site. They would each have notifications just to their login. Office and System would be notifications for a whole entire office, so every user would see it (like meeting notices) while system would be for every user in all systems (like website shutting down for maintenance).
- I want a notification button that displays the number of unread notifications. A user can click on the notification to mark it as read to remove it from the list.
- The user can go to a separate "all notifications screen" to see all the notifications they ever got and search them.

I have a single table like this:

```
*Table: Notifications
notification_id int primary key
entity_type varchar
entity_id int
title varchar
message varchar
created datetime
didRead bit
readDate datetime
```

The entity type is Office, User, Client, Vendors, or System. The id is the corresponding entity id. Since each user for users, client, and vendors are in a different table, it is possible for a separate user, client, and vendor to all have the same id like 4444 etc. The entity type lets me know what table to look into to use the id for.

This works well if the notification is for a user. One record for the one notification for the user. The user reads it and it is marked.

The problem is with system and office notifications. Once I create a single record for a system notification, I can show it to the user by doing a SQL for the their notifications OR system notifications OR office notifications. However, I have NO way of determining if that user read the system or office notification. Since the entity id in the case of system is null or in office it is the office id, if I mark it as read, it will be read for everyone in the office. Only the first person to see it gets alerted.

I could make it so every system notification creates an individual notification for a user, but lets say I have 8 million users. Doesn't that mean for every system notification that I have to create 8 million records? I may be wrong (as in maybe it is no big deal for SQL Server), but something tells me that is bad and will bloat the database fast. Especially since I can see office notifications take off.

I was thinking of making a notification read table containing entity id, entity type, and notification id, but then aren't I just moving the same issue to a different table? Also wouldn't a join to this table now need three items being the entity id, entity type, and notification id? I would assume that would kill performance once the table grew.

**Main Question:** How can I design the table so I am able to read/unread any notification that comes to any user, including their individual notifications and system/office wide notifications? I want system and office notifications to hit a broad range of users, while user, client, and vendor notifications only hit a specific user while allowing all cases to be readable/unreadable.

I use Microsoft SQL server if that makes a difference.

**Edit:**
Tried adding an image (crappy paint skills) to show what I was asking for.
[image: Database idea]

Comment: can you post a diagram of what you want to do? sometimes it helps looking at a visual rather than reading

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I added an image.